# Como customizar o getter no Kotlin?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, kotlin, getters-setters, encapsulamento

Quando criamos uma variável do tipo `val`, se tratando do Java, só é criado o `getter` em relação em relação a mesma. Diferente quando é criado uma variável do tipo `var`, no qual é criado o *getter* e *setter*. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

**Kotlin** usando `val`:

```
class Article construtor(content: String){
    val content: String = content
}
```

Equivalência em **Java**:

```
public class Article {

    private String content;

    public final String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public Article(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Veja abaixo uma customização do *getter* no Java, usando por exemplo o método `toUpperCase()` para que o resultado retorne em "caixa alta" quando se trata de uma *string*:

```
public final String getContent() {
   return this.content.toUpperCase();
}
```

Seguindo esse conceito, qual seria melhor maneira de customizar o *getter* no Kotlin?

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na minha resposta. Achei importante te avisar =D

Comment: Quem negativou a pergunta poderia pelo menos explicar o motivo para que eu possa edita-la e tentar colaborar mais com nossa comunidade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É um pouco parecido.

Em Kotlin, classes não podem ter campos (*fields*), ou seja, elas só podem ter propriedades. Mas, para nossa alegria, a linguagem conta com um mecanismo de [*backing field* implícito](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) (chamado `field`) para quando for preciso usar modos de acesso personalizados.

Sua classe, em Kotlin, poderia ser escrita assim:

```
class Article(content: String) {
    var content: String = content
        get() = field.toUpperCase()
}
```

Código completo para testes

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var art = Article("Alguma coisa")
    println(art.content)
    art.content = "outra coisa"
    println(art.content)
}

class Article(content: String) {
    var content: String = content
        get() = field.toUpperCase()
}
```

[Veja funcionando aqui.](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/f4fp3jeep10lt8a0e3qrv8oshu/rd9iqjsb8acpm1q3s1fif5n7r0)

Answer (score 9):

Para este código aparentemente:

```
var content: String
    get() = this.content.toUpperCase();
    set(value) {
        if (value != "") {
            field = value
        }
    }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Get.kt).

Obviamente fiz um *stter* também só para demonstrar já que ele tem um o `field`. É melhor que no C#, e muito melhor que no Java que nem tem um mecanismo próprio.

Claro que você pode fazer igual ao Java e pode ser útil se usar alguma biblioteca que exige esta forma. Este é um dos problemas que se usar uma plataforma com "história".

Comment: Vai ser difícil de perder o hábito de colocar `;`

Comment: @ramaral ainda bem que os caras já pensaram nisso e deixaram o `;` opcional. =D

Comment: É verdade :))))